# Fetch records from joined table only when condition is met in JPQL and JPA

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have relation as follow: Project has Tasks and Tasks has TimeSheetRecords

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
data class ProjectEntity(
    @Id
    val id: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID(),
    var name: String,
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    val customerId: UUID? = null,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName ="id")
    var tasks: List<TaskEntity> = emptyList(),
    var createDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
class TaskEntity(

    @Id
    val id: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    val projectId: UUID,
    var name: String,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    var timeSheetRecords: List<TimeSheetRecordEntity> = emptyList(),
    var createDate: ZonedDateTime? = null,
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "time_sheet_record")
class TimeSheetRecordEntity(
    @Id
    val id: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @Column(name = "date")
    val date: LocalDate,
    var hours: Int,
    @Column(name = "task_id")
    val taskId: UUID,
    val consultantId: UUID,
    var description: String? = null,
    var createDate: ZonedDateTime? = null
)
```

Now I would like to query this to get Project with Tasks with TimeSheetRecords that match counsultantId and date is between given period. I have tried many different approaches and closest one seems to be:

```
@Query("SELECT project FROM ProjectEntity project " +
    "JOIN TaskEntity task ON project.id = task.projectId " +
    "JOIN TimeSheetRecordEntity  timeSheetRecord ON task.id = timeSheetRecord.taskId " +
    "WHERE project.customerId =: customerId AND task.date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo")
fun findByCustomerIdAndTimeRecordDateBetween(
        @Param("consultantId") consultantId: UUID,
        @Param("dateFrom") dateFrom: LocalDate,
        @Param("dateTo") dateTo: LocalDate,
    ): List<ProjectEntity>
```

Id check works correctly, the problem is that if it match any of TimeSheetRecord with dateRange it returns all of them and I would like to narrow down results of TimeSheetRecords to only be in given date range. Any ideas?

Comment: In JPA, you cannot filter on the `@OneToMany` collection directly in the JPQL query, as it will always fetch the entire collection when accessing it from the parent entity. The best approach here would be to use a DTO projection to get only the data you need. Unfortunately, it means that you won't get the complete ProjectEntity object back, but it will allow you to filter the `TimeSheetRecordEntity` objects by the date.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about using typed or native query with SqlResultSetMapping but it seems to have huge code overhead for such a simple case

Comment: Yes, you're right. Using a SqlResultSetMapping or a NativeQuery might be overkill for this situation. The DTO projection strategy is usually simpler and more readable for these types of queries.